# How to add weight as label to vertex?

Tags: cypher, r-neo4j

I want to add weight to the vertex.

I have the first step going in r-studio. The following code gives a dataframe with the weight:

```
query = "
MATCH (p)-[:REFERS_TO]->(q)<-[:REFERS_TO]-(r)
WHERE (ID(p) < ID(q))
RETURN q.name, COUNT(q) AS Weight
ORDER BY Weight DESC
"
newvalue = cypher(graph, query)
```

How can the weight be added to the vertex as a label? The following does not work for me because it adds the weight to the node instead of the vertex:

```
query = "
MATCH (p)-[:REFERS_TO]->(q)<-[:REFERS_TO]-(r)
WITH q.name, COUNT(q) AS Weight
SET q.weight = Weight
"
cypher(graph, query)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning to say edge instead of vertex? Also, in Neo4j, labels are used to categorize nodes; I'm assuming you want to add the weight as a property to a node or relationship and not set it as a node label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to add the weight to the *edge* (or relationship) rather than to the *node* (or vertex).

In order to add the weight as a property of the edge, you need to bind it to a variable, and then you can set the property as before:

```
query = "
MATCH (p)-[r1:REFERS_TO]->(q)<-[r2:REFERS_TO]-(r)
WITH q.name, COUNT(q) AS Weight
SET r1.weight = Weight, r2.weight = Weight
"
cypher(graph, query)
```

Note I can't tell which of the relationships you want the weight on, so in this example I'm doing both.  The only thing here is I'm binding those two relationships to `r1` and `r2`.  Relationships can have properties just like nodes, so the rest is straightforward.

Comment: thanks, I will try this. In the mean time I experimented with [iGraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html)